# ActiveRecordで外部キーで GROUP BYして集計するとき関連先のカラムを使ってグループ分けするには？

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, sql

### 設例

例えば、TimeEntryとTimeEntryActivityは1対多の関係で、TimeEntryにはactivity_idという外部キーでTimeEntryActivityと関連しています.

```
TimeEntry.group("activity_id").count
  (2.9ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, activity_id AS activity_id FROM "time_entries" GROUP BY "time_entries"."activity_id"
 => {1=>1, 8=>26, 9=>4}
```

そして、TimeEntryActivityでは、次の通り登録されています.

```
TimeEntryActivity.find(8).name
  TimeEntryActivity Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "enumerations".* FROM "enumerations" WHERE "enumerations"."type" IN ('TimeEntryActivity') AND "enumerations"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "enumerations"."position" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 8]]
=> "設計作業"
```

ここで、次のようなデータを取り出すにはどのように書いたらいいでしょうか？

```
{"その他"=>1,  "設計作業"=>26, "開発作業"=>4}
```

使っているデータベースは開発ではSQLite3を使っていますが、本番環境ではMySQLを使っています.

### 追記

Redmineの一部なんですが、TimeEntryActivityはActiveRecord::Baseではなく、Enumerationでしたが、たぶん関係がないと思います.

TimeEntry

```
class TimeEntry < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Redmine::SafeAttributes
  # could have used polymorphic association
  # project association here allows easy loading of time entries at project level with one database trip
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :issue
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :activity, :class_name => 'TimeEntryActivity'
  ...
```

Enumeration
EnumerationはActiveRecord::Baseを承継したクラスでした

```
class Enumeration < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Redmine::SubclassFactory

  default_scope lambda {order(:position)}

  belongs_to :project

  acts_as_list :scope => 'type = \'#{type}\''
  acts_as_customizable
  acts_as_tree
  ...
```

TimeEntryActivity

```
class TimeEntryActivity < Enumeration
  has_many :time_entries, :foreign_key => 'activity_id'
  ...
```

scheme.rb

```
create_table "time_entries", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "project_id",              null: false
  t.integer  "user_id",                 null: false
  t.integer  "issue_id"
  t.float    "hours",                   null: false
  t.string   "comments",    limit: 255
  t.integer  "activity_id",             null: false
  t.date     "spent_on",                null: false
  t.integer  "tyear",                   null: false
  t.integer  "tmonth",                  null: false
  t.integer  "tweek",                   null: false
  t.datetime "created_on",              null: false
  t.datetime "updated_on",              null: false
  t.integer  "ttevent_id"
end
```

書き忘れていましたが、Railsのバージョンは4.2.1です.
よろしくお願いします.

### 追記２

基本方針として、JOINして、pluckで抽出すればいいんですね.
ただ、エラーは解決できませんでした.

```
[34] pry(main)> TimeEntryActivity.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN enumerations WHERE enumerations.type = 'TimeEntryActivity' AND enumerations.id = time_entries.activity_id").group(:name).order(:name).pluck("enumerations.name, count(time_entries.id)").to_h
   (0.4ms)  SELECT enumerations.name, count(time_entries.id) FROM "enumerations" LEFT OUTER JOIN enumerations WHERE enumerations.type = 'TimeEntryActivity' AND enumerations.id = time_entries.activity_id WHERE "enumerations"."type" IN ('TimeEntryActivity') GROUP BY "enumerations"."name"  ORDER BY "enumerations"."position" ASC, "enumerations"."name" ASC
SQLite3::SQLException: near "WHERE": syntax error: SELECT enumerations.name, count(time_entries.id) FROM "enumerations" LEFT OUTER JOIN enumerations WHERE enumerations.type = 'TimeEntryActivity' AND enumerations.id = time_entries.activity_id WHERE "enumerations"."type" IN ('TimeEntryActivity') GROUP BY "enumerations"."name"  ORDER BY "enumerations"."position" ASC, "enumerations"."name" ASC
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: near "WHERE": syntax error: SELECT enumerations.name, count(time_entries.id) FROM "enumerations" LEFT OUTER JOIN enumerations WHERE enumerations.type = 'TimeEntryActivity' AND enumerations.id = time_entries.activity_id WHERE "enumerations"."type" IN ('TimeEntryActivity') GROUP BY "enumerations"."name"  ORDER BY "enumerations"."position" ASC, "enumerations"."name" ASC
from /Users/seventh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `initialize'

[35] pry(main)> TimeEntryActivity.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN enumerations WHERE enumerations.type = 'TimeEntryActivity' AND enumerations.id = time_entries.activity_id")
  TimeEntryActivity Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "enumerations".* FROM "enumerations" LEFT OUTER JOIN enumerations WHERE enumerations.type = 'TimeEntryActivity' AND enumerations.id = time_entries.activity_id WHERE "enumerations"."type" IN ('TimeEntryActivity')  ORDER BY "enumerations"."position" ASC
SQLite3::SQLException: near "WHERE": syntax error: SELECT "enumerations".* FROM "enumerations" LEFT OUTER JOIN enumerations WHERE enumerations.type = 'TimeEntryActivity' AND enumerations.id = time_entries.activity_id WHERE "enumerations"."type" IN ('TimeEntryActivity')  ORDER BY "enumerations"."position" ASC
=> #<#<Class:#<TimeEntryActivity::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007f8e70fa0608>>:0x3fc7387d0304>
```

### 追記３　できました！

```
[13] pry(main)> TimeEntryActivity.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN time_entries ON enumerations.type = 'TimeEntryActivity' AND enumerations.id = time_entries.activity_id").group(:name).order(:name).pluck("enumerations.name, count(time_entries.id)").to_h
   (3.4ms)  SELECT enumerations.name, count(time_entries.id) FROM "enumerations" LEFT OUTER JOIN time_entries ON enumerations.type = 'TimeEntryActivity' AND enumerations.id = time_entries.activity_id WHERE "enumerations"."type" IN ('TimeEntryActivity') GROUP BY "enumerations"."name"  ORDER BY "enumerations"."position" ASC, "enumerations"."name" ASC
=> {"設計作業"=>42, "開発作業"=>6}
```

### 追記４　できました！！

INNER JOINでいいなら、これでもOKですね！
また、テーブル名がわからないときは調べなくてもarel_table使えばいいんですね.なるほど
そして、foreign_keyを設定しているときのjoinsの引数は、idを取ったシンボルを使えるんですね.
例： foreign_key: :activity_id   ==> joins(:activity)

```
[1] pry(main)> TimeEntry.joins(:activity).group(TimeEntryActivity.arel_table[:name]).count
   (1.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, "enumerations"."name" AS enumerations_name FROM "time_entries" INNER JOIN "enumerations" ON "enumerations"."id" = "time_entries"."activity_id" AND "enumerations"."type" IN ('TimeEntryActivity') GROUP BY "enumerations"."name"
=> {"設計作業"=>61, "開発作業"=>9}
[2] pry(main)> TimeEntry.joins(:activity).group('enumerations.name').count
   (0.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, enumerations.name AS enumerations_name FROM "time_entries" INNER JOIN "enumerations" ON "enumerations"."id" = "time_entries"."activity_id" AND "enumerations"."type" IN ('TimeEntryActivity') GROUP BY enumerations.name
=> {"設計作業"=>61, "開発作業"=>9}
```

Comment: それぞれのmodelで関連で定義している部分と、schema.rb上のテーブル定義も見てみたいです。

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます.追記しました.よろしくお願いします.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ちょっと長いですが、こんな感じでどうでしょうか？

```
TimeEntryActivity
  .joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN enumerations ON enumerations.type = 'TimeEntryActivity' AND enumerations.id = time_entries.activity_id")
  .group(:name)
  .order(:name)
  .pluck("enumerations.name, count(time_entries.id)")
  .to_h
```

件数が0件の場合も考慮して外部結合を使っています。

### EDIT

上のSQLが間違っていましたので修正しました。

`LEFT OUTER JOIN enumerations WHERE` => `LEFT OUTER JOIN enumerations ON`

Comment: 返信ありがとうございました.基本方針でJOINして、pluckで抽出すればいいんですね!

ただ、残念ながら、そのままコピーしてもエラーが出てしまい、自分では解決できませんでした.

Comment: ありがとうございました！`LEFT OUTER JOIN time_entries ON`でできました.

Answer (score 1):

関連名をjoinsして、`group.count`で、上手くいかないでしょうか？
groupに指定するのは、関連先の'テーブル名.カラム名'となります。arel_tableを使えばテーブル名を分かってなくても使えますが、belongs_to のforeign_keyを正しく設定しておく必要があります。

```
TimeEntry.joins(:activity).group(TimeEntryActivity.arel_table[:name]).count
```

もしくは、

```
TimeEntry.joins(:activity).group('enumerations.name').count
```

Comment: @Beyondさん、ありがとうございました.無事できましたので、追記しておきました.